# iOS 9 and El Capitan messing up CSS

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iphone, safari

Since Apple's recent update to El Capitan on desktop and iOS 9 on mobile, the css displays of our website have not been working.  I am attaching two screenshots. The first is full screen - not only is the css ignored, but the photo content is not displayed.  The second is a minimized screen which deploys our @media queries for the responsive design. Our code worked on OSX and iOS prior to the updates and works on all other platforms.

Here is the desktop screenshot:
[image]

Here is the mobile screenshot:

[image]

After fixing Safari errors in above code, I still have the issue - css not rendering correctly on kuttlefish.com (since ios9 and El Capitan Mac updates).  One behavior I found that may provide insight: below 603px, the photos on the page suddenly appear. Above 603px, the photos don't display. I am pasting my @603 media css here for anyone who may have an idea.  Tx.

@media only screen and (max-width: 603px) {

```
#contact-form{width:95%;}

.box {width:47.6%;float:left;position:static !important;margin:5% 1% 0 1%;}
.box .preview .thumb{width:100%;height:321px;}
.big-box {width:97.6%;}
.big-box .preview .thumb{width:100%;height:743px;}
.box .idata .description{width:100%;}

.fancybox-wrap{width:96.5% !important;}

#categorieswrapper{height:110px;}
```

}
~

Comment: Looks like the CSS is not even loaded. Do you have errors in the console? Particularly 404 when loading the CSS maybe.

Comment: Red2678:  I'm not very familiar with mac dev tools so am still trying to figure them out. I don't see any 404 error.  In the console, I have a number of "Unexpected CSS token" warnings and several "Invalid CSS Property Declarations at *".  The site is www.kuttlefish.com.  Tx.

Comment: This is the "Unexpected CSS token" line:  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e96c36', endColorstr='#d2522c');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors in your bundled CSS. Chrome (and other browsers are much more forgiving about syntax errors).

Look in the Safari developer tools ([here are instructions on how to enable it](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html)) and you will see errors in the console. There are a few syntax errors in your CSS, here is an example of one:

[image]

In the above you notice the asterisk before the border property, that is invalid CSS. As noted by other users there are a few others, see the comments.

However there are too many to list here, you need to fix them all to get the site to render properly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Red.  I will try to fix those.  Interesting, because the site has worked fine (for 2 years) prior to this latest update. I may come back to you if those fixes don't resolve the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: I fixed the Safari errors and no joy. However, in my {at}media queries, I noticed that below 603px, the photos suddenly appear. Above 603px, they dont. I have added the css code on my 603 breakpoint above. Hope they can give an idea of what's going on. Tx for any additional ideas.

Comment: You still have CSS issues. I took your main.css and put it into http://csslint.net/. There are 10 parsing errors that need to be fixed.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/s9u03hmnlyx9vf4/Screenshot%202015-10-26%2006.45.46.png?dl=0

Comment: That did it. Thanks **VERY** much for your help!!!!!  I had cleared all safari errors but did not know about csslint.net.  Any idea why it was working prior to the latest updates? I was going down all kind of webkit to WKWebView (and other) ratholes trying to stop my head from slamming the wall.  Again, thanks!

Comment: @ian glad I could help! As for your question as to why it worked before, that is an excellent one. I do not know. In Safari 9 they implemented new CSS3 standards http://usee.at/safari9. My guess, where they were once forgiving they now enforce the standard to the letter. Good or bad, IDN, it could go either way. Once again, glad you got it sorted.